# Why does disabling a databound datagridview cause problems?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've recently found a problem with Visual Basic as it handles the `enabling/disabling` of a DataGridView (DGV) that is databound to a `List` of objects.

This program that I'm working on utilizes DGVs that are programmatically filled with information as the program executes. At certain points in the program, these DGVs are enabled and disabled.

I recently added a DGV that is databound to a list of objects. With this new DGV, I've tried to mimic the states of the other DGVs by enabling and disabling it at basically at the same conditions that the other DGVs. This caused exceptions to raise whenever the new DGV would be interacted with in any way, and was particularly difficult to debug.

There were certain conditions where the new DGV did *not* get enabled/disabled, and these exceptions did not get raised. Ultimately, this is how I found that enabling/disabling the DGV was causing the exceptions.

I've currently decided not to bother with enabling/disabling the DGV, but I'm wondering if anybody knows *why* this would happen?

---

If anybody's interested, the DGV was disabled/enabled using these lines of code:

```
newDataGridView.enabled = false
'and
newDataGridView.enabled = true
```

## Update: more information

The DGV with the problem is on a tab control where the DGV with the problem is initially hidden.

If the DGV is disabled, there will be no exception raised, ever. However, the user will of course not be able to interact with the DGV which is a problem by itself.

However, the problem will show up if the tab control is switched to the DGV, then the DGV is enabled then clicked on (in any location). If the tab is switched while the DGV is enabled, the exception occurs immediately.

The exceptions would show up with no stack trace other than a line indicating that the originating source was outside code.

I put breakpoints in all of the event handlers and none of them were called. At this point, no event handlers were being called. In all other scenarios, every event handler works appropriately.

All instances of this exception stopped occurring once I stopped altering the enabled state of the DGV.

Comment: I doubt that particular reason for exception is setting `DataGridView.Enabled = true` or `false`. But changing this property will raise some events and datagridview will be redraw. I think actual reason for exception is somewhere in event handlers of your datagridview.

Comment: I put breakpoints in all of the event handlers and none of them were called. At this point, no event handlers were being called. In all other scenarios, every event handler works appropriately. The exceptions would show up with no stack trace other than a line indicating that the originating source was outside code.

Comment: The DGV with the problem is on a tab control where the DGV with the problem is initially hidden. If the tab is switched to the tab with the disabled DGV, there is no problem. However, the problem will show up if the DGV is enabled then clicked on (in any location). If the tab is switched while the DGV is enabled, the exception occurs.

Comment: All instances of this exception stopped occurring once I stopped altering the enabled state of the DGV.